# Factory design pattern (different signature)

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

Good day

[image]

I would like to implement design according to code snippet below:

```
foreach {
...
    var converter = _convertorsFactory.create(params)
    var result = converter.Convert(string: value)
...
}
```

- The factory should create formatter base on input parameter.
- Formatter should apply method 'Convert' to convert string value to desire output type

Main challenge for me that 'Formatters' have different 'convert' method signature (**different return type**). Thus what signature should be factory 'create' method?

**Quotation**: Thus, please help me to handle what design more suitable in such situation

Comment: Can be done with generics

Comment: Would you like give a example, how it should looks like.  i can't write something like _convertorsFactory. create<T>(params) or converter<T>.convert. Because actual type is known only in factory ( after pass some checks). Thanks at advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public interface IFormatter<T>
{
    T Convert(string x);
}

public interface IFormatter
{
    object Convert(string x);   
}

public abstract class Formatter<T> : IFormatter<T>, IFormatter
{
    public abstract T Convert(string x);

    object IFormatter.Convert(string x)
    {
        return Convert(x);
    }
}

public class DateTimeFormatter : Formatter<DateTime>, IFormatter
{
    public override DateTime Convert(string x)
    {
        // parse or whatever
        return DateTime.Now;        
    }
}
```

let your converters derive from the abstract Formatter class, and you can define your factory method like this:

```
public interface IConverterFactory
{
    IFormatter Create(string x);
}

public class ConverterFactory: IConverterFactory
{
    public IFormatter Create(string x)
    {
        return new DateTimeFormatter();
    }
}
```

Edit:
If you only ever create the formatters via the converter factory, you can remove the generic interface and method, since you won't use them anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It is create, but maybe there solution that will allow return not 'object' type from converter.Convert(string: value), but more specific type ?

Comment: You could cast the object to your concrete type you expect (obviously, you know the type you expect). Or you could make the IConverterFactory generic too, but I don't see much benefit in that.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that the whole point of the `Factory` pattern is to create objects that follow a given interface. But in your case, each of the objects you get has a completely different interface - the only thing they have in common is that they derive from `object` (and in case of `bool`, even that is a bit of a fake).

Think about what the compiler does here:

```
var result = converter.Convert(string: value);
```

What should be the type of `result`? What are you going to *do* with `result`? All you can do is return `object` from `Convert`, but then you'll have to type-cast it to do anything useful anyway, so what value do you get from the Factory?

Think about the interface you want to present here; what do you do with the `result`? Build the interface around that, and you can return this interface from your factory method. But C# is mainly a strongly typed language - you can't just return three different types with three different interfaces from a method and do anything useful with them without explicit type-casting (or `dynamic`, but if you need that in your core logic, C# might not be the best language for you).